# Linked EditText Boxes for Paste

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have four EditText boxes that together make up a value. Each box should contain 1 number. When I enter a number into one box the focus should move to the next box. I have "faked" a link between the boxes by modifying the focus when the text is changed. The following code works but I want to allow for the user to paste in values that will then be split across the EditText boxes. So if I paste "123" in box[0], box[0] should contain "1" and box[1] should contain "2" etc. I attempted to add `android:maxLength="1"` to the XML but when I attempt to paste content, the maxLength validation removes all but the first character.

What is the best way to split the contents of a paste across the 4 EditText boxes?

EnterNumberLayout.java

```
    public class EnterNumberLayout extends LinearLayout {
    EditText[] textBoxes;

    public static final int NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES = 4;

    public EnterNumberLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        this.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);

        textBoxes = new EditText[NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES];

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES; i++){
            EditText et = (EditText) inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_box, null);
            //et.setOnKeyListener(new BackspaceKeyListener(et));
            et.addTextChangedListener(new MoveFocusWatcher(et));
            et.setTag(i);

            textBoxes[i] = et;
            this.addView(et, i);
        }
    }

    private class MoveFocusWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private View view;
        public MoveFocusWatcher(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if ((int) this.view.getTag() < NUMBER_OF_ENTRIES - 1) {
                (textBoxes[(int) this.view.getTag() + 1]).requestFocus();
            }
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    }

}
```

number_box.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="number|none"
android:ellipsize="start"
android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few ways to do this, but I'd probably remove the text limit of 1 on the edit text and manage the length with a text watcher.

Here, if text is pasted into the first edit1 then the text watcher will split the values up into the other edit text fields.  You need to be careful when changing text in the afterTextChanged callback since the change will initiate another call to the method.  Since the text length in edit1 is only one after our processing, the next callback does nothing.

```
public class TextGroup extends LinearLayout {


   EditText edit0;
   EditText edit1;
   EditText edit2;
   EditText edit3;

   public TextGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context);

      View view =  LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.edit_text_special, null);
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

      edit0 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text0);
      edit1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text1);
      edit2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text2);
      edit3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text3);

      edit1.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
      this.addView(view,  lp);
   }

   TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {

      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int start, int count, int after) {

      }

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
         if ( edit1.getText().length() >= 3) {
            edit3.setText(String.valueOf(edit1.getText().toString().charAt(2)));
         }
         if ( edit1.getText().length() >= 2) {
            edit2.setText(String.valueOf(edit1.getText().toString().charAt(1)));
            edit1.setText(String.valueOf(edit1.getText().toString().charAt(0)));
         }



      }
   };

}
```